# Neo4j Cypher : avg of positive values return negative average

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am running this query on my Neo4J graph :

```
match (person:Person)-[r:KNOWS]->(friend:Person)
return avg(r.duration)
```

The *duration* attribute of the *KNOWS* relation is a double value, always populated and always positive.

My issue is that this query returns a negative value.
I validated this with this query :

```
match (person:Person)-[r:KNOWS]->(friend:Person)
where has(r.duration) and r.duration > 0
return avg(r.duration)
```

It also returns a negative value.

Any idea around the reason behind this behavior ?

Comment: what version of Neo4j are you using. I just created a small tested console here and it seems to be ok ? http://console.neo4j.org/r/ei28q2

Comment: I am using Neo4j 2.2.2.

Comment: can you create a console with some data, like I did

Comment: I investigated deeper :
- The attribute type is int, not double.
- The sum is bigger than the int max value

Not sure if it is possible to force the attribute type in the neo4j console, I reproduced it with longs : http://console.neo4j.org/r/chtfmz

Comment: apart from the problem in cypher, I think that at the application level this behavior should throw an exception

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the console, indeed int max value is overflown.

I can't say what would be the best way for your use case, I would need to investigate further, however in the meantime, if you cast the scores to float values, then they are positive :

```
MATCH (person:Person)-[r:KNOWS]->(friend:Person)
WITH toFloat(r.score) AS score
RETURN sum(score), avg(score)
```

**UPDATE**

Mmh apparently the value is rounded with the above solution, so disregard it for the moment